# SQL retrieving attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, security

If I have the following schema:

```
    EMPLOYEE (Fname, Minit, Lname, Ssn, Bdate, Address, Sex, Salary, 
    Super_ssn, Dno)
    DEPARTMENT (Dname, Dnumber, Mgr_ssn, Mgr_start_date)
    DEPT_LOCATIONS(Dnumber, Dlocation)
    PROJECT(Pname, Pnumber, Plocation, Dnum)
    WORKS_ON(Essn, Pno, Hours)
    DEPENDENT(Essn, Dependent_name, Sex, Bdate, Relationship)
```

And I want Account Bob to retrieve all the attributes of EMPLOYEE and DEPARTMENT 
except for Salary, Mgr_ssn, and Mgr_start_date, How will I do that?

Comment: Did you try with an idea? If yes, what is it? Post it here.

Comment: I tried this CREATE VIEW V
SELECT Fname, Minit, Lname, Ssn, Bdate, Address, Sex, Super_ssn, Dno
FROM EMPLOYEE;

Comment: Include conditions to fetch on `Bob` specific data.

Comment: what? I don't understand what that means?

Comment: You posted *I want Account Bob to retrieve all the attributes of...*. Add conditions to your view query.

Comment: Also see [SQL row column acl](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+row+column+acl) and [sql column acl site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+column+acl+site%3Astackoverflow.com).